# Double background showing in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, double

Here is the link to the problem >> http://vubscs.tk/Forum-C-Lectures

background in IE8 is repeating but it is working fine in FF, Chrome and Opera, I even use, background:url() no-repeat;

Here is the screen shot in IE 8

[image: Here is the screen shot in IE]

Comment: Which IE are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not properly closing your form that is enclosing the`vpassmain` div. Properly encapsulate that form and it should work fine.

This is how it looks now:

```
<form action="/Forum-C-Lectures" method="post">

<br /><br />

<center> /* opened center tag with no closing tag */
<div class="vpassmain">
<div class="vpass">
Password: <input type="password" class="textbox" name="pwverify" value="" />
<div class="vbtn">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Verify Password" />
</form> /* form closes here */
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Fixed version

```
<form action="/Forum-C-Lectures" method="post">
    <br /><br />
    <center>
        <div class="vpassmain">
            <div class="vpass">
                Password: <input type="password" class="textbox" name="pwverify" value="" />
                <div class="vbtn">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Verify Password" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</form>
```

Comment: @Programer Due to the DOCTYPE you specified IE was rendering your block of code literally as it was written. Div opens here -> closes there. By opening a form tag and closing it before your the end tags for your divs and center tags it was picked up by the browser as the beginning of new tags. The other poster posted a screenshot with this phenomenon, you can see how another center tag and `vpssmain` div where opened "after" the form closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have two DIVs with the class "vpassmain", so the background image will be applied to both DIVs.

[image]